# What are the usage limitations of Bitly shortening API?

Tags: bit.ly

I've tried Bitly's shortening API to shorten some URL's and after signing up and getting a username/API key, I've been able to shorten URL's in my local computer. But once, the code got deployed to a test server, the shortening fails. Any idea on what could possibly the source for this, or how to track the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using PostMan ( chrome ) or HTTP Requestor ( firefox / my preference ) to post the JSON request you are sending to the API, review the error code and see if it has any useful errors (http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ is nice for reviewing it ).

Alternatively if you have no UI in the server use a CURL request from the server.

What language are you sending this in by the way?  I am assuming JSON (not XML) is being sent eventually?  What kind of server is it? Could you post the error code please?

Best of Luck!